# TextBlock Text property not updating on updating its source Binding property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, properties

I have the following code snippet in XAML.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="01*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="03*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="01*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Name="btnPrevious" Grid.Column="0" Content="Previous" Click="btnPrevious_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Name="txtBlockName" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <Button Name="btnNext" Grid.Column="2" Content="Next"  Click="btnNext_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

This generates the following output as in Figure1.

[image: Figure1.]

The code behind this is shown below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

    public string SelectedName
    {
        get
        {
            return namesList[1];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != namesList[1])
            {
                namesList[1] = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedName");
            }
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        namesList.Add("ABC");
        namesList.Add("DEF");
        namesList.Add("GHI");


        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = namesList[0];
        namesList[0] = namesList[1];
        namesList[1] = str;

        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = namesList[2];
        namesList[2] = namesList[1];
        namesList[1] = str;

        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }



    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

The `Text` property of `TextBlock` is bound to the `SelectedName` property. And it is not being updated on updating the `SelectedName` property. Although my class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and defines its `NotifyPropertyChanged` behavior, it still doesn't work.

While debugging, I put some break points to watch `SelectedName` property value and I observe that it is updating as per requirement but the `Text` property of `TextBlock` is not updating. As shown in Figure2.

[image: Figure2.]

I have seen a lot of questions and solutions on Internet, but nothing solves my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two answers given so far, the only one that comes even close to what I think is a reasonable alternative is the second option presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39716289) (i.e. after *"if you want to 'Update' SelectedName you could"*).

That said, it seems to me that you would do well to change your data structure so that it more closely models what is actually happening in the user interface. Your code will be a lot easier to write and understand, and will be simpler, if you take the time to do so.

In this particular example, that means that, since (it appears) you want to be able to navigate through three different text values, you should use the property simply to present the current text value, and use an index variable to keep track of which value is selected. For example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // Don't make fields public. If you do want to expose the list
    // use a public read-only property. And even there, think carefully
    // about whether you want callers to be able to modify the list; you
    // can return a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` that wraps your list if
    // you only want callers to be able to examine the contents, rather than
    // modify it.
    //
    // Also, make any field that you never change "readonly".
    private readonly List<string> namesList = new List<string>();

    // Here's the index that keeps track of which string is selected
    private int _index;

    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return namesList[_index]; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        namesList.Add("ABC");
        namesList.Add("DEF");
        namesList.Add("GHI");

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_index > 0)
        {
            _index--;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedName));
        }

        // I don't know what you expect this to do. You are setting the window's
        // "IsEnabled" property to false, which doesn't seem useful. More likely,
        // you intend to set the "Previous" button's enabled state, but even there
        // you really only want to set it to false if the _index value is 0. If the
        // _index value had been 2 and was just set to 1, you still want the
        // "Previous" button enabled. This would actually be an excellent place for
        // you to learn how to implement an ICommand, to have its CanExecute() method
        // return a value based on the _index value (where the "Previous" ICommand
        // object would return true unless _index is 0, and the "Next" ICommand
        // object would return true unless _index is namesList.Count - 1). Then you
        // can bind the button's "Command" property to the appropriate ICommand
        // object for the button and WPF will automatically deal with enabling
        // or disabling the button according to the command's state
        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_index < namesList.Count - 1)
        {
            _index++;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedName));
        }

        // See comment above.
        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.DynamicInvoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Note that with any of the changes proposed in either of the two other answers, you are still left with bugs related to the navigation between each text value. The initial click of a button may work, but after that your data structure would be incoherent and you would not get the results it appears that you want.

The example in this answer addresses all of those issues, along with your original concern.

Comment: I am confused with my code and the code of Dan's? Please clarify the difference between them to me. Thanks

Comment: @Peter, 100% with you, I did not know what "IsEnabled = false" meant to do either, came to the same conclusions, but I didn't want to introduce too many differences in the code to point out the change notification miss...which I think was the question's intention

Comment: @Waqas: the salient difference between your original code and the answer in Dan's post is that Dan raises the `PropertyChanged` event for the `SelectedName` property when its value changes, while your code does not. Both of your code examples will work correctly only with the first button click. My example has the same difference with your code in that it raises the `PropertyChanged` event, with the additional difference that it will work on subsequent button clicks rather than just the first button click.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I have tried Dan's second option too, it is the same as was my code. it also updates the property only, not the UI.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I have tried my code with some piece of your code it works correctly. And updates property as well as UI.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting "SelectedName", you could've made it readonly.

PropertyChanged is never raised.

If you want the binding to notice it, you should do

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedName");
```

after you have changed the index #1  of _namesLIst,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly List<string> _namesList = new List<string>();

    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return _namesList[1]; }            
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _namesList.Add("ABC");
        _namesList.Add("DEF");
        _namesList.Add("GHI");

        DataContext = this;
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var str = _namesList[0];
        _namesList[0] = _namesList[1];
        _namesList[1] = str;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedName));
        IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var str = _namesList[2];
        _namesList[2] = _namesList[1];
        _namesList[1] = str;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedName));

        IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

if you want to 'Update' SelectedName you could

```
    public string SelectedName
    {
        get { return _namesList[1]; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _namesList[1]) return;
            _namesList[1] = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedName");
        }
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var str = _namesList[0];
        _namesList[0] = _namesList[1];
        SelectedName = str;            
        IsEnabled = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var str = _namesList[2];
        _namesList[2] = _namesList[1];
        SelectedName = str;            
        IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: What would to do when I have controlling more textblocks with more and different text properties to bind with them. Your code always updates the property  'SelectedName' on clicking either Next or Previous.

Comment: the code does not update SelectedName, it Notifies it has changed ,
and what ever its bound to it will update with current value

Comment: Now what is the difference between your code and my code?

Comment: the only diff is that you didn't updated  "SelectedName", nor you notify about it's change...that's it
1st version notifies , 2nd version indirectly notifies when setting the property , that is what I thought you were asking,, why the value does not get updated on the UI ?.
.. and the answer is ... 
because the UI didn't know about it.

Comment: I have tried your second option too, it is the same as was my code. it also updates the property only, not the UI.

Answer (score 0):

SelectedName Setter property has never been invoked. So you can update the TextBlock.Text by using BindingExpression.UpdateSource() method like below,

```
 private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = namesList[0];
        namesList[0] = namesList[1];
        namesList[1] = str;
        BindingExpression be = txtBlockName.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
        be.UpdateSource();

        this.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```